# How do I group and sort values into a dictionary?

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to find the latest version of multiple files within a directory. Currently, I'm calling `GCI` per file, but that is extremely slow, so I want to instead cache all the results by unique file name and then just perform a lookup in the cache.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
Gci $filePath -Recurse | ?{ -Not $_.PSIsContainer } | Group-Object Name
```

I'm trying to convert this to the powershell equivalent of the C# code:

```
group.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Values.OrderByDescending(v => v.ModifiedAt).First().FullName)
```

How would I accomplish this in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do to create a hashtable of files would be to create an empty hashtable, and then populate it with the results of your GCI:

```
$files = ${}
GCI $filepath -Recurse -File | Group Name | ForEach{ $files.Add($_.Name, ($_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime)) }
```

Or if all you want is the most recent file, add `| Select -Last 1` after the `Sort LastWriteTime`. If all you care about is the path, you could even do `| Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName`.

```
$Files = ${}
GCI $filepath -recurse | Group Name | ForEach{ $files.Add($_.Name, ($_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName)) }
```

Comment: Turns out I actually came up with the same thing as I was waiting for an answer, except different syntax. Thanks. `Gci $path -Include $extensions -Recurse | ?{ -Not $_.PSIsContainer } | Group-Object Name | % { $cache[$_.Name] = ($_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1).FullName }`